# Get C XOR return value

Tags: c

In the `for` loop, it prints the correct value `11100001` in each loop, but the main call `print char_str` is blank.

I hope it can return `11100001` as `char`.

```
//xor
char * xorencrypt(char * a, char * b) {
    size_t alen = strlen(a);
    size_t blen = strlen(b);
    char * encrypted = malloc(alen + 1);

    int i;
    for (i = 0; i < 8; i++) {
        encrypted[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
        printf("%s\n", encrypted[i]);
    }
    encrypted[alen] = '\0';

    return encrypted;
}

main {
    char * char_str = xorencrypt("11011000", "00111001");
    printf("%s\n", char_str);
}
```

Comment: Your code would not compile.

Comment: Do you want to xor the char values of `'0' ^ '1'` or flip `'1' and '0'`?

Comment: The variable `blen` is not used.  Remove it or use it to find the minimum length of the two C-Strings.

Comment: If I add #includes and add parentheses to your main function, to get the code to compile, I get a segmentation fault...

Comment: Remember that character `'1'` usually has the value 49 and `'0'` usually has the value 48 (and even if those numbers are wrong, they are guaranteed to differ by 1).  The value of `48 ^ 49` is `1`, not `'1'`.

Comment: Technically, memory allocated inside a function is allocated on the stack, so returning from the function technically de-allocates it. That may not be your problem here (it usually isn't, because you won't have written over the memory, yet), but try it first with the new string allocated and passed in from `main`, just in case.

Comment: @JohnC: there's a `malloc()` in the code there...that isn't the problem.

Comment: @JohnC: WHAT? Take your hands off that compiler **now** before you hurt yourself...

Comment: @DevSolar, memory allocated inside a function isn't valid outside of a function. It usually works, but not because it was planned that way. Library functions have _you_ pass the string in, remember.

Comment: correct value 11100001 what do you mean by that  ? a[i] ^ b[i] will XOR the ASCII values of 1 or 0 not giving you 11100001 by any means ?

Comment: Also, @JonathanLeffler is absolutely right. Explaining what the output looked like would have made that obvious. You're printing ASCII characters `'\000'` and '`\001`', not `'0'` and `'1'`. Try `encrypted[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]) + '0';`

Comment: @JohnC: I stand by my statement. Please read up on "stack" vs. "heap". `malloc()` allocates *heap* memory. That's the whole purpose of it.

Comment: Why do you get the length of the strings, but loop for a fixed number iterations?

Comment: On my previous comment about the segmentation fault, I'm not sure how you're even getting the correct values printed during the loop at the line `printf("%s\n", encrypted[i]);`. I think you're being helped by your system initializing `encrypted` to `'\0'`, which mine doesn't do, but even so you're using `encrypted[i]` and not `&encrypted[i]` - which should mean you're trying to print the string starting at address 0x0 or 0x1, hence the segmentation fault. (And even then it still isn't quite right as Jonathan Leffler points out).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A reworked version of the code that assumes you are dealing exclusively with strings of the binary digits `'0'` and `'1'`.  If you are dealing with more general strings, you will need a different solution.

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

static
char *xorencrypt(char *a, char *b)
{
    size_t alen = strlen(a);
    char *encrypted = malloc(alen + 1);
    assert(alen == strlen(b));
    assert(encrypted != NULL);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < alen; i++)
    {
        assert(a[i] == '0' || a[i] == '1');
        assert(b[i] == '0' || b[i] == '1');
        encrypted[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]) + '0';
        putchar(encrypted[i]);
    }
    encrypted[alen] = '\0';
    putchar('\n');

    return encrypted;
}

int main(void)
{
    char *char_str = xorencrypt("11011000", "00111001");
    printf("%s\n", char_str);
    free(char_str);
    return 0;
}
```

Amongst the changes:

1. Error check the memory assignment.  Using `assert()` is a bad way to do it in production code, but it does ensure that you check that the memory is allocated.
2. Check that the strings are the same length.
3. Remove unused variable `blen`.
4. The `static` is optional; it means the code compiles cleanly under the stringent options I use (which require a prototype declaration of every non-static function before it is defined or used).
5. The loop index `i` is of the same type `size_t` as `alen` to avoid warnings about comparing signed and unsigned values.  I'm using the C99 style 'declare a variable in a `for` loop' notation.
6. The upper bound of the loop is based on the measured length of the strings, not a fixed constant.
7. The original version of the XOR operation either generated a null `'\0'` or a control-A `'\1'` for each character.
8. The revised version of the crucial XOR operation ensures that the result is a printable digit.
9. The `printf("%s\n", encrypted[i]);` in the original passed a character to be printed as a string. If your compiler wasn't warning you, turn on the warning options or get a better compiler.
10. If you'd written `printf("%s\n", &encrypted[i]);` you would have had problems, potentially, with a string that is not guaranteed to be null terminated inside the loop (though you did null terminate the string after the loop, which was good).
11. The code in `main()` frees the allocated memory.  It is good practice to ensure there is a `free()` for every `malloc()`.
12. I prefer to explicitly return 0 from `main()`, even though C99 says you don't have to.

---

<sup>*This answer was started while the question was active.  Then life got in the way.*</sup>

Answer (score 3):

Your code needs a bit of refactoring.

1) You need to include some headers

```
#include <stdint.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
```

2) the 'main' function should return an int

```
int main() {
    /* code here */
    return 0;
}
```

3) You should make sure the call to malloc succeeds

```
char * encrypted = malloc(alen + 1);
assert(encrypted != (char*)0); /* requires #include <assert.h>
```

4) You should be careful when xor'ing ones and zeros. You are handling chars like integers

you are xoring zeros (value 48 in ascii) with ones (value 49 in ascii)

```
encrypted[i] = a[i] ^ b[i];
```

you want something like this instead

```
int a_i = a[i] - '0';
int b_i = b[i] - '0';
encrypted[i] = (a_i ^ b_i) + '0';
```

Comment: You could sanely write `encrypted[i] = (a[i] ^ b[i]) + '0';`.  As written, it works, but the evaluation is effectively `a_i ^ (b_i + '0')` which is probably not what you were thinking of.  Always be very careful about mixing logical operators with arithmetic operators.